# Java equivalent of D3.js .curveBasis

Tags: javascript, java, d3.js, spline

I'm reading the article [Generating SVG Jigsaw Puzzles](https://dev.inventables.com/2016/02/26/generating-svg-jigsaw-puzzles.html).
I would like to implement the procedures in Java, but having
trouble finding a graphics primative in java.awt.geom that is parameterized
the same as the javascript D3 library's `d3_shape.line().curve(d3_shape.curveBasis)`.

The curve is drawn in d3.js using six points: two end points and four control points.
I have tried using various combinations of CubicCurve2D and QuadCurve2D but haven't
been able to reproduce it.

Can anyone point me to a method in Java that will allow me to draw a curve using
two end points and four control points?

A picture of the curve that I would like to produce:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a 5-degree Bezier curve calculated point by point.

Call `getB5Point` with 6 base points and a variable param `t` (0 to 1):

```js
const points = [
  {x: 40, y: 130},
  {x: 120, y: 100},
  {x: 10, y: 20},   
  {x: 290, y: 10},  
  {x: 150, y: 110},
  {x: 270, y: 140},
]

const getB5Point = (p, t) => {
  const coef = [1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1];
  let factor = Math.pow(1 - t, 5);
  let x = 0, y = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    x += p[i].x * coef[i] * factor;
    y += p[i].y * coef[i] * factor;
    factor /= (1 - t);
    factor *= t;
  }
  return {x, y};
}

const svg = d3.select('svg');
for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    svg.append('circle')
      .classed('marker', true)
      .attr('cx', points[i].x)
      .attr('cy', points[i].y)
      .attr('r', 5);
  if (i > 0) {
    svg.append('line')
          .attr('x1', points[i - 1].x)
          .attr('y1', points[i - 1].y)
          .attr('x2', points[i].x)
          .attr('y2', points[i].y)
  }
}

for (let t = 0; t <= 1; t += 0.01) {
    const point = getB5Point(points, t);
    svg.append('circle')
      .classed('dot', true)
      .attr('cx', point.x)
      .attr('cy', point.y)
      .attr('r', 2);
  
}
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.marker {
  fill: red;
  stroke: red;
}

line {
  stroke: black;
  fill: none;
}

.dot {
  fill: green;
  stroke: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width='300' height='175'>
  
</svg>
```